# Kaggle login and unzip file to store in s3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

1. Create a lambda function for python 3.7.
2. Role attached to the lambda function should have S3 access and lambda basic execution.
3. Read data from https://www.kaggle.com/therohk/india-headlines-news-dataset/download and save into S3 as CSV. file is zip  how to unzip and store in temp file

Getting Failed in AWS Lambda function:

> Lambda Handler to download news headline dataset from kaggle

```
import urllib3
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

http = urllib3.PoolManager() 

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket_name = 'news-data-kaggle'
    file_name = "india-news-headlines.csv" 
    lambda_path = "/tmp/" +file_name
    kaggle_info = {'UserName': "bossdk", 'Password': "xxx"}
    
    url = "https://www.kaggle.com/account/login"
    data_url = "https://www.kaggle.com/therohk/india-headlines-news-dataset/download"
    
    r = http.request('POST',url,kaggle_info)
    r = http.request('GET',data_url)
    
    f = open(lambda_path, 'wb')
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size = 512 * 1024):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
    f.close()
    data = ZipFile(lambda_path)
    # S3 Connect
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
    
    # Uploaded File
    s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put(Key=lambda_path, Body=data, ACL='public-read')
    
    return {
        'status': 'True',
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Dataset Uploaded'
    }
```

Comment: Hey @DKBOSS, please check the formatting of the code in your post - Python is very sensitive to indentation and something seems to be messed up.

Comment: Hey DKBOSS, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please explain what exactly is not working? Looking at the code I would say that the authentication you do is not saved. So your subsequent `GET` request is unauthorized. Also remember, that the ZIP archive and the extracted CSV should not be bigger than 512MB combined, otherwise you run out of disk space.